# How to execute mulitple console c# programs in a single project in VSTS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am new to .Net Programming, I am writing and executing c# console programs in Visual Studio 2010, Can you help me how to execute multiple programs in a single project , i tried the option as" exclude from project" but the .cs file is vanished from the project . Can u please help me how to execute multiple programs in the single project . because each time i have to  create new project for executing a simple program.

Comment: I think you need to define what you mean with "execute" and "program" in this case.

Comment: I am writing C# console programs , Suppose if i want to  write a C# program for addition of two numbers , then i will open a new projecta and write the code in the program.cs now i have written the program and have executed the program . Now I want to write  another program for finding primenumber , for doing this i have to create new project.
I want to write two programs in the same project , but i want to execute them individually.

Comment: You can add multiple console app projects to a single solution if you want.

Comment: @Matthew Watson : Can u please tell me  how to add multiple console app projects in a single solution , that would be a great help for me, this is what i want

Comment: @MatthewWatson : R u there , i need a help , please suggest me the solution.

Comment: right click in the solution and choose "add" -> "new project"

Comment: Sorry I was at lunch. :) To add a new project, just select from the Visual Studio menu: `File | New | Project...` or right-click the "Solution" from within Solution Explorer and select `Add | New Project" from there.

Answer (score 3):

One console project generates one .exe file. You cannot have multiple console C# programs in single project, if by "program" you mean .exe file.

If by "program" you mean the abstract concept of computer code, you must specify more clearly what exactly you're trying to achieve.

**edit**: After seeing your comment and definition of "program", I suggest the following: Create two *classes* (right click on the project -Add> Class), then create code in Program.cs that executes either Class1 or Class2 like this

```
static void Main(string[] args) { 
    Class1.Execute(args); 
    // Or: 
    Class2.Execute(args);
}
```

..given that `Class1` and `Class2` both define a method with the signature `static void Execute(string[] args)`

Comment: @ Nilzor : Thanks Nilzor . I am trying it in VSTS2010 and will let you know if i have any issues. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 0):

In the solution explorer, you can right-click on a project. 
In the context menu select Debug\Start new instance.

You can do this for multiple projects before running your main project.